# amp-consent fails on automation testing

Tags: javascript, automation, amp-story

I've created an amp-story page with amp-consent. But when I run automation testing, I am not able to get the consent part tested as it is not accessible with queryselection of javascript. I get "null whenever I try to find the 'Accept' or 'Decline' buttons.
I have it in below sequence:

```
<amp-story>
 ...
 <amp-consent>
  ...
  <amp-story-consent> ...
```

Then it adds the HTML content of the consent inside "#shadow-root" component which doesn't have any possible query selector.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the entire code?, amp components have properties to make them work that you are not listing in your question